# MariaDB and ipv6 operations

Tags: mariadb

Why does this query return correct result in the MySQL and null result in the MariaDB?

```
select inet6_ntoa(inet6_aton('200d:31c4:1905:9eb2:3c7f:c45c:de78:42cd') & ((~INET6_ATON('::') << (128 - 97))))
```

Returns in the MySQL:

`200d:31c4:1905:9eb2:3c7f:c45c:8000::`

Returns in the MariaDB:

`null`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is in the `~` operator. For MariaDB it is [defined as follow](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/bitwise-not/):

> Bitwise NOT. Converts the value to 4 bytes binary and inverts all bits.

When applied to the result of [`INET6_ATON()`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/inet6_aton/) the length of the binary value get truncated. The query

```
select HEX(INET6_ATON('::')), HEX(~INET6_ATON('::'))
```

in MariaDB will [produce the following values](https://dbfiddle.uk/vsszBmnE):

```
HEX(INET6_ATON('::'))  -> 00000000000000000000000000000000
HEX(~INET6_ATON('::')) -> FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

*(interestingly, it converts the value to 8 bytes instead of 4 bytes, at least for the MariaDB server running on https://dbfiddle.uk/)*

Where as in MySQL the [bitwise negate operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-functions.html#operator_bitwise-invert) will [produce the following value](https://dbfiddle.uk/LVHpoTyE):

```
HEX(INET6_ATON('::'))  -> 00000000000000000000000000000000
HEX(~INET6_ATON('::')) -> FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

From there on, in MariaDB, all remaining bit operations you have like shifting and `&` will fail or will produce incorrect values, which ultimately results in `0` or `null`, where in MySQL you will get the correct result.

Comment: Outstanding feature [MDEV-10526 Support bitwise operators for binary and bit types](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-10526). Linked MDEV to here to show the very useful case as OP presented.